# Баг python regex?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Обнаружил очень странный момент. Регулярное выражение из приведенного ниже примера не срабатывает в python3.9, но прекрасно находит на сайте https://regex101.com/r/w7Hi7C/1. Есть идеи, с чем может быть связано?

```
import re

def find(param, value):
    return re.match(fr'(?:([0-9\.\-\+]+)\*)?(\-)?{param}(?:\*([0-9\.\-\+]+))?', re.sub(' ', '', str(value)))

find('a1', 'x < a1')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так ваш пример с regex101 и в вашем коде сработает. А строка из вашего кода найдётся, если вместо `re.match` использовать `re.search`. Потому, как `re.match` сопоставляет с начала строки, а подстрока `a1` в вашем коде явно идёт не с начала.
О [разнице](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) между этими функциями недвусмысленно [изложено в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

Comment: В этот момент мне стало стыдно, что я забыл об этом нюансе...